# Django strange behaviour

Tags: python, django, class-variables

I have a view in Django which calls external library/class. The problem is that for some reason Django keeps caching results coming from previous calls of that class.

Please consider the following simple example:

Django view:

```
from some_path import Demo
def test_view(request):
    demo = Demo()
    result = demo.do_something()
    return render(request, 'test.html',
                            { 'result':result }
                )
```

Demo class:

```
class Demo():
    result = []

    def do_something(self):
        self.result.append(1)
        self.result.append(2)
        self.result.append(3)
        return self.result
```

You expect result to be [1, 2, 3], right ?
WRONG!

The first time a page is loaded you'll get the correct result. But on all following requests it will keep incrementing: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]... [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] ...

So my question is obvious - what is going on here ?
How do i receive [1, 2, 3] every time i call a class inside Django view ?

Django 1.7 / MacOS X.

Comment: My question is described in full in the following tutorial:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define `result` in `__init__` as an instance attribute.

```
class Demo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.result = []

    def do_something(self):
        self.result.append(1)
        self.result.append(2)
        self.result.append(3)
        return self.result
```

If you print `result` in your code then you will get that `result` is assigning just once,

```
class Demo():
    result = []
    print result

    def ...
        .
        .

d = Demo()
print d.do_something()
print d.do_something()
e = Demo()
print e.do_something()
>>> 
[]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

`result` is a mutable object, whenever you made an instance of the class it refer `result` to the same reference.
In case of Immutable object:-

```
class Demo():
    result = 1

    def do_something(self):
        self.result += 1

d = Demo()
d.do_something()


d.do_something()
e = Demo()
e.do_something()
print d.result, e.result
```

Output:-

```
>>> 
3 2
```

Comment: I'll accept that answer because it solves the problem. But why does this happen ?

Comment: Even I suggest this way :P

Comment: @Termos check the updated code, i think i solved what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try initializing the `result=[]` inside your `do_something` method something like this ?

```
def do_something(self):
        result = []
        result.append(1)
        result.append(2)
        result.append(3)
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Case 1:
Here we have declared the result and some_string as static Class variable 
"""
class Demo_1():
    result = []
    some_string = ""

    def do_something(self):
        Demo_1.some_string = Demo_1.some_string + "Python "
        self.result.append(1)
        self.result.append(2)
        self.result.append(3)
        return self.result

demo = Demo_1()
print Demo_1.result
result = demo.do_something()
print Demo_1.result

demo = Demo_1()
result = demo.do_something()
print Demo_1.result

demo = Demo_1()
result = demo.do_something()
print Demo_1.result

print result
print demo.some_string

print "Demo_1 class attributes :-", dir(Demo_1)

"""
Case1 Output :
    []
    [1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
    Python Python Python 
    Demo_1 class attributes :- ['__doc__', '__module__', 'do_something', 'result', 'some_string']

As you can see both result and some_string exists in Demo_1's attributes 
which you can access by both by Class name as well as it's instance 
"""

print "-----------------------------------------------------------------"

"""
Case 2:
Here we have declared the result variable as Class instance variable.
So each time we create an instance of class it creates new memory for that instance.
"""
class Demo_2():

    def __init__(self):
        self.result = []
        self.some_string = " "

    def do_something(self):
        self.result.append(1)
        self.result.append(2)
        self.result.append(3)
        return self.result

demo = Demo_2()
result = demo.do_something()
print demo.result

demo = Demo_2()
result = demo.do_something()
print demo.result

demo = Demo_2()
result = demo.do_something()
print demo.result

print result
print "Demo_1 class attributes :-", dir(Demo_2)
print Demo_2.some_string

"""
Case2 Output :
    [1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2, 3]
    Demo_1 class attributes :- ['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'do_something']
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "bl.py", line 83, in <module>
        print Demo_2.some_string
    AttributeError: class Demo_2 has no attribute 'some_string'


As you can see Class Demo_2 has no attributes result or some_string as 
they are instance variable.
"""
```

See more about **static Class variable** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)